# How to compare multiple columns(More than 2) in a selected area with excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

So I found this VBA code online that compares 2 ranges and highlights the differences in cell values and I'm trying to edit it such that I can highlight a selected area with a certain number of rows and column and compare it with another selected area with the same number of rows and column, but I can't really figure it out so I was wondering if there is any other way around it that allows me to do so.

```
Sub CompareTwoRanges()


    Set myRange1 = Application.InputBox("Select the first Range:", "CompareTwoRanges", "", Type:=8)
    Set myRange2 = Application.InputBox("Select the second Range:", "CompareTwoRanges", Type:=8)


    For Each c1 In myRange1
        For Each c2 In myRange2
            If c1.Value = c2.Value Then
                c1.Interior.ColorIndex = 38
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! In the code that you found, the "exit for" stop comparing the rest of the cells. May be you have to kill it to make it suitable for you.
Besides, please give us more detail about what you want to compare, and the result, because is not clear. May be picture with the desired result could help. Bests

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Sub CompareTwoRanges()
    Dim i As Long

    Set myRange1 = Application.InputBox("Select the first Range:", "CompareTwoRanges", "", Type:=8)
    Set myRange2 = Application.InputBox("Select the first cell in the second Range:", _
                                        "CompareTwoRanges", Type:=8)

    Set myRange2 = myRange2.Resize(myRange1.rows.count, myRange1.Columns.count) 'match size
 
    For i = 1 to myRange1.Cells.Count
        With myRange1.Cells(i)
            If myRange2.Cells(i).Value <> .Value Then
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 38
                Exit For
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```